# Resetting index after removing rows from Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to split an option chain into a separate data frame for rows with just the calls ('C') from the column, Right.

```
options_df
```

| Index | Right |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | P |
| 1 | P |
| 2 | P |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | C |
| 5 | C |

I try to make a new data frame, df, to hold the calls ('C'):

```
df = options_df
df.drop(df[df["Right"] == 'P'].index)
```

This returns the data frame, df, but unfortunately it keeps the indexing from the original data frame, options_df:

```
df
```

| Index | Right |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | C |
| 5 | C |

Ideally, the data frame for df would look like this:

| Index | Right |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | C |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C |

But, it does not.

I've tried to correct with resetting the index, as below:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it also does not work and gives me back the entire original data frame, options_df:

```
df
```

| Index | Right |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | P |
| 1 | P |
| 2 | P |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | C |
| 5 | C |

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I just cannot figure this one out. Thank you for you help!

Comment: `df.drop(df[df["Right"] == 'C'].index)` this is not an in-place operation. You have to assign it back and then reset index.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem!

Comment: Actually, to make thing simple, if you select with only one condition, you don't need to use .drop(), just select the rows of the condition you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `.drop()`, just select the rows of the condition you want and then reset the index by `reset_index(drop=True)`, as follows:

```
df = df[df["Right"] == 'C'].reset_index(drop=True)




print(df)


  Right
0     C
1     C
2     C
```

Answer (score 2):

When you reset your index you need to add `inplace=True`

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Or, assign the result back to df with the line as you've written it:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you - this also helped! in summary, I needed to do re-assignment: ```df = df.drop(df[df["Right"] == 'P'].index)``` and ```d f= df.reset_index(drop=True)```